# Overwrites permission don`t changed discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I updated almost everything by bot after discord.js v12 but I have a problem with the last command, the permissions do not apply, what could be the problem?

```
 if(userTickets.has(message.author.id) || message.guild.channels.cache.some(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === message.author.username + 's-ticket')) {
        message.author.send("EN: You already have a ticket!");
    } else {
        let guild = message.guild;
        message.guild.channels.create("- " + `${message.author.username}s-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            createOverwrite:[
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                },
                {
                    id: guild.id, 
                    deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                },
                {
                    id: '',
                    allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                }
            ]
        }).then(ch => {
            ch.setParent('');
            ch.send("=")
            userTickets.set(message.author.id, ch.id);
            let sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("=")
            sChannel.send("Created " + ch.name + " channel.")
            //console.log(userTickets);
            console.log(userTickets)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `createOverwrite`, use `permissionOverwrites`.

```js
        let guild = message.guild;
        message.guild.channels.create("- " + `${message.author.username}s-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites:[
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: guild.id, 
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                }
            ],
            parent: '' //parent id here
        }).then(ch => {
            ch.send("=")
            userTickets.set(message.author.id, ch.id);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can also instead of setting the parent after the channel was made, just set channel while making it.